# OPENROWSET read old xls file

Tags: sql-server, excel, openrowset, sql-server-2022

I have a problem on SQL SERVER 2022. When I want to select data from an **XLSX** file, everything works perfectly, but when I want to select data from an older **XLS** file, I get this message:

> The Microsoft Access database engine cannot open or write to the file ''. It is already opened exclusively by another user, or you need permission to view and write its data.

```
DECLARE @path NVARCHAR(MAX) = '\\SRV-SQL\MSSQLSERVER\Data\Test\Test.xls'

SET @path = REPLACE(@path, @@SERVERNAME, 'localhost')

DECLARE @cmd NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(''Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'',''Excel 12.0;Database=' + @path + ';HDR=NO;'',
''SELECT * FROM [MyTestSheet$]'')'

EXEC(@cmd)
```

Comment: You need to use JET for 2005 or older documents.

Comment: Are you sure the file isn't open in Excel? Or that the database service account has permission to read that folder and file? And why is the obsolete `xls` format used at all? It's not for "compatibility" - even Microsoft Online rejects `xls` unless you pay for it.

Comment: When I'm trying use Jet I get this message:

Msg 7438, Level 16, State 1, Line 7 The 32-bit OLE DB provider "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" cannot be loaded in-process on a 64-bit SQL Server.

Comment: That's because SQL Server is 64-bit and JET is 32-bit only. The real question, I suppose, is why are you still using Excel 2003 files (I misrecalled in my [original comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77904911/openrowset-read-old-xls-file#comment137343312_77904911) what year the last version that used xls was).

Comment: And that's *exactly* why it's better to just reject `xls` and tell whoever created that file to use the correct format. Are you *absolutely sure* the file isn't open though?

Comment: In any case, `OPENROWSET` is more of a last-chance solution with severe drawbacks. It's definitely not a data virtualization feature. Why not use the proper tools like SSIS or even a Python script to import the data into the database?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure the file is not open. We have thousands of such files. SQL has read and write rights to this file (files are in filetable). If I convert the file to xlsx, it works fine.

I will have to convert all the files to the new format.

I need to use OPENROWSET because the data is updated using a procedure on another action

Comment: Why not use some integration like SSIS or write a python script or something

Comment: Instead of `Excel 12.0;` in the extended properties have you tried `Excel 8.0;` when working with the legacy _Excel 97-2003 Workbook (.xls)_ files? It's mentioned in the Connectivity Information section of [Download and install Microsoft 365 Access Runtime](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/download-and-install-microsoft-365-access-runtime-185c5a32-8ba9-491e-ac76-91cbe3ea09c9), as well as the download pages for other versions of the driver... but the formatting is usually junk making the information illegible.